# How do I draw a line in iOS swift in the viewDidLoad() function?

Tags: swift, cgcontext, uigraphicscontext

I keep getting the following error when trying to draw a green line in my viewDidLoad(). It is important that I do it here because it's in between new labels when they are being placed down. The error is:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see 
 the backtrace, 
 please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
```

The code for drawing the line(s) is below:

```
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
                        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0)
                        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,self.hexStringToUIColor("#008500").CGColor)
                        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0,CGFloat(top+40))
                        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(screenWidth*2), CGFloat(top+40))
                        CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

Comment: That is most certainly the wrong place to draw the line. Rethink that assumption / statement.

Comment: How do you mean? Oh and top is the variable that represents the distance from the last label

Comment: Yes, you can either implement drawRect in your view, add a 3pt high, colored view to your layout, or add a CAShapeLayer with the appropriate CGPathRef to your view's layer. There are may be more ways, but doing it in viewDidLoad is never going to be one of them.

Comment: Okay, the place of your code gets even more wrong. Firstly you are not in the context of drawing anything. Secondly you are not at a point in the view lifecycle where any layout information is present, meaning that your `top` will be invalid as well. You either add a new view with the correct dimensions to your current view (laying it out has to happen in viewDidLayoutSubviews or similar) or you have to subclass your view and draw something in its `drawRect`.

Comment: Yes, but the top is based off labels that have been added just before that. I'll try the drawRect function now

Comment: See, I had it up in viewdidload so that it goes right underneath each label as it is added, but im not sure how to do it without knowing where each label will be

Comment: it sounds like you should really take a look at the interface builder first. getting layout to work from code will be massive pain.

Comment: Ya but I have to get the code to add it programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like you just want to add a line to your user interface programmatically.  To do that, just use a `UIView` to create the line.  Set its `backgroundColor` to the color you want.  The height you specify for the `frame` will be the thickness of the line.

```
// Add a green line with thickness 1, width 200 at location (50, 100)
let line = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 1))
line.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.view.addSubview(line)
```